# Intersection of 2 array of strings with different upper and lower case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I want to get the intersection of 2 arrays of strings. The first array has different upper and lower case. The resulting array I want should respect the first arrays casing, but the comparison between the 2 should ignore the upper/lower case. E.g.

```
letters = ['Aaa', 'BbB', 'CCC']

permitted = ['aaa', 'bbb']
```

The result should be:

```
['Aaa', 'BbB']
```

Im doing:

```
letters.map(&:downcase) & permitted.map(&:downcase)
```

But this returns `['aaa', 'bbb']`

What's a neat way of doing this? The longer way of doing it is:

```
letters.each { |letter|
    if permitted.include?(letter.downcase)
        accepted.push(letter)
    end
}
```

But is there a shorter/neater way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method for comparing string in a case-insensitive manner, [`String#casecmp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-casecmp):

```
letters = ['Aaa', 'BbB', 'CCC']
permitted = ['aaa', 'bbb']

letters.select{|l| permitted.detect{|p| p.casecmp(l) == 0 } } # => ["Aaa", "BbB"]
```

You can also [use regular expressions](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247). :)

```
letters = ['Aaa', 'BbB', 'CCC']
permitted = ['aaa', 'bbb']

letters.grep(Regexp.new(permitted.join('|'), Regexp::IGNORECASE)) # => ["Aaa", "BbB"]
```

Comment: Great answers thanks, im going to go with your first one as i personally tend to steer clear of regex:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `select`:

```
search = permitted.map(&:downcase)
letters.select{|letter|
  search.include?(letter.downcase)
}
```

Or even neater (imho):

```
-> search { 
  letters.select{|x| search.include?(x.downcase)}
}.call(permitted.map(&:downcase))
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/C9xR)

Comment: That "neat" version is cryptic as hell :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: As I said, my opinion only. It just feels as an atomic expression, unlike the first one

Comment: @potashin Thanks. I prefer your first one though. Im going to accept Sergio's answer though as its a one-liner but this is great too